# npx react-native run-android error after updating react native

Tags: react-native

I have upgraded my react native and created a new project.

When i run npx react-native run-android iam getting the below error.

D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\cli.js{  "root": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject",  "reactNativePath": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native",  "dependencies": {},  "commands": [    {      "name": "log-ios",      "description": "starts iOS device syslog tail"    },    {      "name": "run-ios",      "description": "builds your app and starts it on iOS simulator",      "examples": [        {          "desc": "Run on a different simulator, e.g. iPhone 5",          "cmd": "react-native run-ios --simulator \"iPhone 5\""        },        {          "desc": "Pass a non-standard location of iOS directory",          "cmd": "react-native run-ios --project-path \"./app/ios\""        },        {          "desc": "Run on a connected device, e.g. Max's iPhone",          "cmd": "react-native run-ios --device \"Max's iPhone\""        },        {          "desc": "Run on the AppleTV simulator",          "cmd": "react-native run-ios --simulator \"Apple TV\"  --scheme \"helloworld-tvOS\""        }      ],      "options": [        {          "name": "--simulator [string]",          "description": "Explicitly set simulator to use. Optionally include iOS version betweenparenthesis at the end to match an exact version: \"iPhone 6 (10.0)\"",          "default": "iPhone 11"        },        {          "name": "--configuration [string]",          "description": "Explicitly set the scheme configuration to use",          "default": "Debug"        },        {          "name": "--scheme [string]",          "description": "Explicitly set Xcode scheme to use"        },        {          "name": "--project-path [string]",          "description": "Path relative to project root where the Xcode project (.xcodeproj) lives.",          "default": "ios"        },        {          "name": "--device [string]",          "description": "Explicitly set device to use by name.  The value is not required if you have a single device connected."        },        {          "name": "--udid [string]",          "description": "Explicitly set device to use by udid"        },        {          "name": "--no-packager",          "description": "Do not launch packager while building"        },        {          "name": "--verbose",          "description": "Do not use xcpretty even if installed"        },        {          "name": "--port [number]",          "default": 8081        },        {          "name": "--terminal [string]",          "description": "Launches the Metro Bundler in a new window using the specified terminal path."        }      ]    },    {      "name": "log-android",      "description": "starts logkitty"    },    {      "name": "run-android",      "description": "builds your app and starts it on a connected Android emulator or device",      "options": [        {          "name": "--root [string]",          "description": "Override the root directory for the android build (which contains the android directory)",          "default": ""        },        {          "name": "--variant [string]",          "description": "Specify your app's build variant",          "default": "debug"        },        {          "name": "--appFolder [string]",          "description": "Specify a different application folder name for the android source. If not, we assume is \"app\"",          "default": "app"        },        {          "name": "--appId [string]",          "description": "Specify an applicationId to launch after build.",          "default": ""        },        {          "name": "--appIdSuffix [string]",          "description": "Specify an applicationIdSuffix to launch after build.",          "default": ""        },        {          "name": "--main-activity [string]",          "description": "Name of the activity to start",          "default": "MainActivity"        },        {          "name": "--deviceId [string]",          "description": "builds your app and starts it on a specific device/simulator with the given device id (listed by running \"adb devices\" on the command line)."        },        {          "name": "--no-packager",          "description": "Do not launch packager while building"        },        {          "name": "--port [number]",          "default": 8081        },        {          "name": "--terminal [string]",          "description": "Launches the Metro Bundler in a new window using the specified terminal path."        },        {          "name": "--tasks [list]",          "description": "Run custom Gradle tasks. By default it's \"installDebug\""        },        {          "name": "--no-jetifier",          "description": "Do not run \"jetifier\" – the AndroidX transition tool. By default it runs before Gradle to ease working with libraries that don't support AndroidX yet. See more at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jetifier.",          "default": false        }      ]    }  ],  "assets": [],  "platforms": {    "ios": {},    "android": {}  },  "haste": {    "providesModuleNodeModules": [      "react-native"    ],    "platforms": [      "ios",      "android"    ]  },  "project": {    "ios": {      "sourceDir": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\ios",      "folder": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject",      "pbxprojPath": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\ios\AwesomeProject.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj",      "podfile": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\ios\Podfile",      "podspecPath": null,      "projectPath": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\ios\AwesomeProject.xcodeproj",      "projectName": "AwesomeProject.xcodeproj",      "libraryFolder": "Libraries",      "sharedLibraries": [],      "plist": [],      "scriptPhases": []    },    "android": {      "sourceDir": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\android\app",      "isFlat": false,      "folder": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject",      "stringsPath": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml",      "manifestPath": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml",      "buildGradlePath": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\android\app\build.gradle",      "settingsGradlePath": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\android\settings.gradle",      "assetsPath": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\assets",      "mainFilePath": "D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\awesomeproject\MainApplication.java",      "packageName": "com.awesomeproject"    }  }}
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 200
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Failed to parse React Native CLI configuration. Expected running 'npx.cmd --quiet --no-install react-native config' command from 'D:\React Native Playground\AwesomeProject' directory to output valid JSON, but it didn't. This may be caused by npx resolving to a legacy global react-native binary. Please make sure to uninstall any global 'react-native' binaries: 'npm uninstall -g react-native react-native-cli' and try again.

```
My package.json

{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the error message, it sounds like npx may be resolving to a legacy react-native binary. If you have previously installed react-native-cli, this is likely the culprit, as the cli is now included along with the react-native binary. Per react-native docs:

> If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues.

If you haven't already, try uninstalling react-native and react-native-cli with npm and then using npx (comes with node) for future react-native usage.

```
npm uninstall -g react-native react-native-cli
```

Then,

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```